# Linuxfoundation LFCS cert - Exam Topics Confusion

Tags: networking, remote, accounts

I am preparing to take the LFCS exam on linuxfoundation and I am stuck.
In the exam objectives from the Cert Guide Manual they list the topics you need to be prepared for.

But a confusion arised when I encountered these two different topics:

1. Managing local users accounts
2. Managing user accounts

What's the difference ? I can't understand, really. I e-mailed them but the answer wasn't clear, they said: "*local users are those stored on the computer itself (think of profiles on your laptop), whereas user accounts are network level profiles (so you can log into different machines with them)*"

Aren't these the same ? Users on the box with which you either do local stuff or remote stuff on different machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "traditional" way was (is) to have a user account information locally, i.e in `/etc/password`, `/etc/group` etc. But that is not easy to manage when users freely access other computers on the network and/or have their home-directory on some networked drive.

For the latter setup it is more easy to have user account information (incl password) in an LDAP database somewhere on the network and configure the local machines in such a way that they authenticate the login against this information instead of having a local copy of that information. That makes it much easier to manage than if you have to update `/etc/password` etc. on every machine on the network.

Before LDAP became popular there was [YellowPages/NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) which solved the problem in a different way.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I will take a look at LDAP. Your information is valuable. I searched a lot on the web and couldn't find any explanation about these two topics.

Comment: @jojo621 if this resolves your issue, please take a minute to mark the answer as accepted (below the up/down arrows to the left of the answer). THat way future visitors know the issue is resolved.